# Parallelized code dependent from other functions

Tags: r, function, parallel-processing

Here is the structure of a function I have created inside which a parallelization has been implemented.

```
    parallelized.function <- function(...){

          # Function used in the parallelization
            used.in.par <- function(...)
          # Function needed by used.in.par (auxiliars)
            aux1<-function(...)
            aux2<-function(...)
          #---------------------------------------------------#
          # PARALLELIZATION PROCESS
            suppressMessages(library(foreach))
            suppressMessages(library(doParallel))

                   ..................................

               %dopar%{ used.in.par(...) }

          #---------------------------------------------------#
         return(something)   
         }
```

The code works, but it supposes to define `aux1` and  `aux2` inside `parallelized.function` to work well (which needs a lot of lines of code).

**Is there any way to call `aux1` and `aux2` functions instead of writing all the code inside `parallelized.function`?**

I tried creating new scripts with aux functions and writing `source(".../aux1.R")` and `source(".../aux2.R")` inside `parallelized.function` without success.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` package would do that for you. In order to acccess function that was not defined in the current environment, you should use `.export`; and loading required packages on each of the workers would be possible by using `.packages` option.

```
foreach(
  ...,
  .export = c('aux1', 'aux2'),
  .packages = c(...)
) %dopar% {
  ...
}
```

Note that loading `foreach` and `doParallel` package inside foreach loop is not required. But you missed the part when you register clusters.

Comment: Thank you so much @G. Becker. Defining both functions and objects in `.export` (always between "") solves my problem. Anyway, I don't understand your last two sentences.

Comment: To clarify. I wanted to notice that in order to use `%dopar%`, you should register parallel backend in the first place. For example by `registerDoParallel` function.

Comment: Ok, yes I did `registerDoParallel(no_cores)` specifying the number of cores to use. I didn't write it because I didn't want to focus the question in how to parallelize.

Comment: Apart from functions, are objects also exported using `.export` ?